# For which value of $x \in R $ the following series converges $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {2x+n}{2+n^3x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For which value of $x \in R $ the following series converges

$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {2x+n}{2+n^3x^2}$

The series of the absolute values is $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {|2x+n|}{2+n^3x^2}$

and applying the root test:
$ lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{ \frac {|2x+n|}{2+n^3x^2}}= lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac {|2x+n|^{ \frac {1} {n}}}{(2+n^3x^2)^{ \frac {1} {n}}}$

$\frac {|2x+n|^{ \frac {1} {n}}}{(2+n^3x^2)^{ \frac {1} {n}}} \sim \frac {1}{(x^2)^{ \frac {1} {n}}} \rightarrow 0 $ if $x \ne 0$

Is it correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $\dfrac{1}{(x^2)^{\frac 1n}} = 0$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. it tends to 0

Comment: Does it tend to $0$ if $x=1$?

Comment: no, this is not correct. Observe that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{c}=1$ for any $c>0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x^2}=1$ when $x\neq 0$. HINT: for $n>0$ you can rewrite your series as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2x+n}{2+n^3x^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2(x/n)+1}{2/n+(nx)^2}<\frac{2x+1}{x^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$$

Comment: well, in the previous hint you need to consider absolute value on each series and $x\neq 0$. Also the index is wrong, it must be $n$ instead of $k$.

Comment: @Masacroso  The result should be $ x /ne 0 $ while in your solutIon the series converges for any x

Comment: This is why I wrote my last comment. If $x=0$ then what I wrote previously is not defined because $\frac{2x+1}{x^2}=\frac10$ what is meaningless.

Comment: @Masacroso $\sum_{1=1}^\infty\frac{2x+n}{2+n^3x^2} =\sum_{1=1}^\infty\frac{2(\frac{x}{n})+1}{\frac{2}{n}+n^2x^2} =\sum_{1=1}^\infty\frac{2(\frac{x}{n})+1}{\frac{2}{n}+(nx)^2} =\sum_{1=1}^\infty\frac{\frac{2x+1}{n}}{x^2(\frac{2}{nx^2}+n^2)}= \frac{2x+1}{x^2}\sum_{1=1}^\infty\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{2}{nx^2}+n^2}=\frac{2x+1}{x^2}\sum_{1=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}*\frac{nx^2}{2+n^3x^2}=(2x+1)*\sum_{1=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2+n^3x^2}<(2x+1)*\sum_{1=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: @Masacroso I don't have $x^2$

Comment: @Anne your calculus is wrong. Observe that $2(x/n)+1\neq\frac{2x+1}n$